# Trying to Attach one rigid body simulation with 2 ropes to an jewel (solid object)

Tags: animation, rigidbody

[image]

[image]

[image]

hi the main problem is when i try to use the rigid body simulation the ropes separate from the jewel i want to know if i can activate the rigid body and not separate it from the main model

Comment: Hello, it's a bit vague, does it mean that the ropes are made of a series of bones? Also, what kind of animation are you trying to achieve, etc?

Comment: hi sorry for my bad explanation, im trying to replicate this on the second 0:37 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ix3eh4NpPZc , the ropes are only a single mesh and i added a cube to it (the cube is the soft body) there are 2 ropes so 2 soft bodys and the rope move along the cube, it doesnt have bones, and i can attach the person to only one rope but if i add 2 the bottom part of the 2 ropes separate from each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

Create 3 objects: the 2 ropes object (2 meshes within 1 object) / the cube (your character) / a plane.

Subdivide the plane, give it a *Cloth* simulation, assign its 2 last vertices to a vertex group that will be the cloth *Pin Group*, increase the *Speed Multiplier* value of the simulation if you want the animation to go faster:

[image]

Give a *Surface Deform* modifier to your rope object, with the plane as *Target*, click on the *Bind* button:

[image]

Select the cube, shift select the rope, switch to Edit mode, select 3 vertices, make the vertices parent with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]

Play the animation and you'll get that:

[image]